# CSS scale on hover, space between overlay and border

Tags: html, css

When I hover on a div there seems to be a small gap on the left and black edge on the right.Here is the left and right part of the div;

[image]

Here is the fiddle and codes that reproduces the issue;
https://jsfiddle.net/hqk54p9k/

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="poster-list">
        <div class="poster">
            <div class="poster-overlay">
                HELLO
            </div>
            <div class="poster-image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.poster {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.66667%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: top;

  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:hover {
    border: 4px solid #1599d6 !important;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .poster-image {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .poster-overlay {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.poster-list {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

What's the cause of this problem?

Comment: On the JSFiddle it does not seem to be any space between the border and the div.

Comment: Can you try to zoom 125% in browser.

Comment: @IsmailGül no there is no gap..can  you please post images with issue?

Comment: @IsmailGül Which browser(s) are you using?

Comment: @BDawg Chrome and IE

Comment: @Leothelion I posted the images above.

Comment: Anyone think this might be an OS-specific issue? I'm on OSX and don't see this problem when using Chrome.

Comment: Perhaps this link helps: https://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/05/subpixel-rendering-2/

Answer (score 0):

Weird. Its an optical illusion.

I just tried and changed the `.poster-image { background-color: red; }` color to `green` and it goes away. Also `blue` has no "space", only `red`.

I do not see any "gap" on the left side, only the black gap on the right, when `background-color: red` is set (using Chrome/Ubuntu).

**edit**

Changed CSS to this

```
.poster-image {
  ...
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: white;

  &:hover {
    outline: 4px solid #1599d6 !important;
    ...
```

If the `border: 1px` then there is a tiny white border, and the effect does *not* occur.

If the `border: 0px` and the tiny white border isn't there, the effect happens.

When I magnify using browser zoom, the effect does *not* increase in size. It remains to be a tiny line, less than a full pixel wide.  I think it is a rendering issue from the anti-aliasing the browser does to the edge.

Comment: It's seems like that on the example. But in the app background image can be seen from that gap. Check out the image above. And if you try to remove position:absolute from .form class. You can see the problem at the top of the poster. Black and white background can be seen between .poster-image and .poster's border.

Comment: Confirmed, the different color of the background can be seen through the gap. And this time even changing the color of `.poster-image` doesn't help, the background can be seen through the gap.

Comment: I added `left: -10px;` and `right: -10px;` to `.poster-image`, but even that would not make the "gap" disappear completely. The black "shines through" on the edge. I think that is a rendering issue from the anti-aliasing the browser does to the edge. Better use `.poster { background-color: white; }` and bake the border using `outline: transparend` rather than `padding`.

Comment: Updated my answer.